# FFmpeg adding click to beginning of audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got an odd issue that's been bugging me for a while. I'm converting another format to video using FFmpeg; the conversion takes place prior and is fed into FFmpeg to be finally converted to an mp4.

Oddly, I seem to be getting a little click at the start of the resulting video; it's not present in the original audio but shows up in the final video.

Here is the [sample audio](https://www.sudomemo.net/Testing/click_issue/debug_audio.wav). You'll notice that it has no pop at the start.

Here is the [raw video input](https://www.sudomemo.net/Testing/click_issue/debug_raw_video.bin).

Here is the [video my command is generating](https://www.sudomemo.net/Testing/click_issue/out.mp4).

Here is the command I'm using to reproduce the issue (the actual conversion takes place in a Python script feeding FFmpeg the video via stdin and the audio via a temp file)

```
cat debug_raw_video.bin| ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel info -y -s 256x192 -r 30 -f rawvideo -thread_queue_size 600 -pix_fmt rgb8 -i pipe:0 -f s16le -ar 11025 -ac 1 -guess_layout_max 0 -i ./debug_audio.wav -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart -acodec aac -strict experimental -vf scale=512:384:flags=neighbor -threads 0 -preset medium -tune animation ./out.mp4
```

FFmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
```

Also have the same issue with this version:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
```

Why am I getting a little click/pop at the beginning? I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while.

Comment: try skipping for 1/2 second or so at the begin of the audio trak . see whether u get same pop noise at +skip on the timeline

Comment: I just tried that by specifying -itsoffset 00:00:02 before the -i flag for the input audio. No click, though the video was extended past to accommodate the audio slightly

Comment: Actually, there's less of a click and more of a woosh (starts at the offset specified, roughly) that shouldn't be there when I do that.

Comment: guessing here.. try an audio filter to decrease volume over the problem interval

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you're specifying that the input audio is raw, but it's not:

```
$ file debug_audio.wav
debug_audio.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 11025 Hz
```

So I imagine the click you're hearing is the wav header being processed as audio. If I remove the related options, `-f s16le` and `-ar 11025`, `ffmpeg` correctly determines that the audio input is in wav format and produces a click-less output:

```
cat debug_raw_video.bin | ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel info -y -s 256x192 -r 30 -f rawvideo -thread_queue_size 600 -pix_fmt rgb8 -i pipe:0 -ac 1 -i ./debug_audio.wav -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart -acodec aac -strict experimental -vf scale=512:384:flags=neighbor -threads 0 -preset medium -tune animation ./out.mp4
```

Comment: HOLY MOLY! THANK YOU! You have made my day infinitely better! That fixed it right up!